# Python API POST request: hard-coded works but variables does not - Error 500

Tags: python, api, rest

I am having an issue and I can't figure out why and how to fix it. I built a basic API in Flask to grab data from Google Trends. I am now writing a Python script to use that API. The API needs 5 query `string` parameters (`keyword1, keyword2, start, end, country`). When I call that API using POSTMAN, it's giving me a 200 response and the correct data (generating a `csv` file and storing it). Now i need to implement the code to make a POST request for that service. I am having issue with 2 query parameters: `keyword1` and `keyword2`, when I am harcoding those parameters in the payload, it's working perfectly (200 response and storing the file). When I am using variables instead of harcoding `keyword1` and `keyword2`, I am getting a 500 error. What I have done is:

1. Verified the type of `keyword1` and `keyword2` and it's a `string` as expected in my query parameter
2. Checked that both variables are not null and they are not

Not sure what is the issue here, I spent the last 4 hours to try to understand what is wrong

**500 error Code**

```
start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2020-01-15'
country = 'GB'

#Few others methods between

def request_trends_service():
    current_position = get_position_reader()
    new_position, keyword1 = read_line_from_csv(current_position)
    new_position, keyword2 = read_line_from_csv(new_position)
    save_new_position(new_position)

    url = "https://gtrendsv4-f2ya73vqjq-uc.a.run.app/request_trends?"

    payload = {
    "keyword1": keyword1,
    "keyword2": keyword2,
    "start": start,
    "end": end,
    "country": country
    }

    parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    url += parameters
    r = requests.post(url)

    print(r.text.encode('utf8'))
```

**Code that works (2 lines changed)**

```
start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2020-01-15'
country = 'GB'

#Few others methods between

def request_trends_service():
    current_position = get_position_reader()
    new_position, keyword1 = read_line_from_csv(current_position)
    new_position, keyword2 = read_line_from_csv(new_position)
    save_new_position(new_position)

    url = "https://gtrendsv4-f2ya73vqjq-uc.a.run.app/request_trends?"

    payload = {
    "keyword1": "sun",
    "keyword2": "fun",
    "start": start,
    "end": end,
    "country": country
    }

    parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    url += parameters
    r = requests.post(url)

    print(r.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I'd do a `print(repr(keyword1))` just to verify that the value is what's expected. Ditto for keyword2

Comment: Oh damn, I think you got the issue! Seems I have a "\n" at the end of my string. Let me remove it to see

Comment: Thanks for your help, was the issue!!